# How to print() to Xcode console in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

So I tried to put a print statement while debugging in a SwiftUI View.

```
print("landmark: \(landmark)")
```

In the following body.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                Text("Favorite only")
            }
            ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                print("landmark: \(landmark)")
                if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                    NavigationButton(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))            
    }
}
```

Compiler errors out:
[image: Xcode compiler error]

So, what is the proper way to print to console in SwiftUI?

EDIT:
I made Landmark conform to *CustomStringConvertible*:

```
struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {

var description: String { name+"\(id)" }

var id: Int
var name: String
.....
```

I still get the "String is not convertible to any" error. Should it work now?

Comment: Does your landmark conform to ```CustomStringConvertible```?

Comment: Your question is about printing but you can't compile since you have an error. Fix the error first and I'm sure the print will work fine.

Comment: I edited the question. For some reason I had to clean and build again, then the other error when away.

Comment: Have you tried to add `return` before NavigationButton?

Comment: On Xcode 12.4 all prints end up in the debug area only when I use a real device.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

You can easily add a print statement anywhere in a function builder by simply storing its return value in a wildcard, effectively ignoring it:

```
let _ = print("hi!")
```

No setup or other verbosity needed!

#### Why does this work while a regular `print()` doesn't?

The way SwiftUI's `@ViewBuilder` (and result builders in general) is that they consume any values in a closure that aren't used otherwise (e.g. if you just have `42` on its own line). The `print` function returns `Void` (nothing), which the builder would have to build into a view, so it fails. By instead assigning it to a variable (in this case `_`, basically a variable that you can never access), the `Void` is never offered to the view builder in the first place.

You could argue the builder should simply accept and ignore `Void` values, but the idea is that your builder closures should not have side effects (I'd remove `print` statements after finishing debugging too)—you should not rely on these closures being called at certain times.

Comment: Geez why must some things be so weird in SwiftUI, so many things feel like "workarounds" or "hacks" just to reach a simple result.

Comment: An extremely simple solution for a weird problem - thanks!

Comment: @Big_Chair I'm learning SwiftUI and I kinda agree with you. But at the same time, restrictions can result in more structure. That is: everything within the `body` is to be of type `View` or something with a compiler directive that makes it known it's to be ignored.

Comment: @mfaani Reading my old comment from multiple months ago is kind of funny, now that I actually got a really good grip on SwiftUI. I agree with you. I think the problem is that the answer by juliand didn't mention the reason why it wouldn't work and lets people believe this is how it's done for no reason. Also, Xcode's error messages could also be more clear to explain why it's not possible :)

Comment: @Big_Chair Good thoughts! I've expanded on my answer with an explanation of why it works and some thoughts on why view builders work this way.

Comment: I wanted to put a NSLog statement in the body property expecting a WidgetConfiguration. The above answer didn't work. When I explicitly added a return statement in the code (as mentioned in @Darkisa's answer), then NSLog worked...without having the LHS.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD Unlike `View.body`, `Widget.body` is not annotated with any kind of [result builder](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md) (the magic behind SwiftUI), so you don't need any kind of special magic to support print statements and whatnot. The standard rules of Swift still apply just the same, so you have to write `return` explicitly if your body consists of multiple statements/expressions.

Answer (score 66):

Here's a helper `Print( ... )` View that acts like a `print( ... )` function but within a View

Put this in any of your view files

```
extension View {
    func Print(_ vars: Any...) -> some View {
        for v in vars { print(v) }
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

and use inside of `body` like so

```
Print("Here I am", varOne, varTwo ...)
```

or inside a `ForEach {}` like so

```
self.Print("Inside ForEach", varOne, varTwo ...)
```

Note: you might need to put `Print()` into a `Group {}` when combining with existing views

Comment: This modification lets you use "print" syntax: func Print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") -> some View {
    let string = items.map{String(describing: $0)}.joined(separator: separator)
    print("Print:", string, terminator: terminator) // could add other stuff here
    return EmptyView()
}
self.Print("view named", self.someName, "number:", self.num)

Comment: Version with NSLog for anyone wanting timestamps:
```extension View
{
    func NSLogView(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> some View
 {
        NSLog(format, args)
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Try right-clicking on the live preview play button and selecting 'Debug Preview from the popup

Comment: About Debug Preview for SwiftUI in macOS, It seems that the latest Xcode (11.3) hasn't supported to print a log to Xcode's console with `print()` yet. AFAIK only a breakpoint with a log message action can do that for now. Or, as another workaround, you can use Debug Preview with Console.app so that you can see the debug log in the app. Please note that you'd need to use `NSLog()`, since `print()` doesn't work for output to Console.app.

Comment: In Xcode 12.3, printing a log to Xcode's console seems still not working :(

Answer (score 19):

You can print in the body structure but to do so you have to explicitly return the view you want to render. The body property inside a `View` is just a computed property like any other in Swift that implicitly returns the view. And just like any other computed property, you can perform operations inside the computed property as long as a value is explicitly returned. For example, this will throw an error when you try to print because there is no explicit return:

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
  @State var isOpen = false
    
  var body: some View {
    print(isOpen) // error thrown here
    
    VStack {
      // other view code
    }
  }
}
```

But if we explicitly return the view we want then it will work e.g.

```swift
struct SomeView: View {
  @State var isOpen = false
    
  var body: some View {
    print(isOpen) // this ok because we explicitly returned the view below
    
    // Notice the added 'return' below
    return VStack {
      // other view code
    }
  }
}
```

The above will work well if you're looking to view how state or environment objects are changing before returning your view, but if you want to print something deeper down within the view you are trying to return, then I would go with @Rok Krulec answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use print() remembering that all SwiftUI View content are (a) implicit closures and (b) it is highly recommended to decompose views as much as possible to have simple structure, so it might look like the following...

```swift
struct Model: Identifiable {
    let value: String
    var id: String {
        value
    }
    init (_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var showFavoritesOnly = false
    @State var listData: [Model] = [Model("one"), Model("two"), Model("three")]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Favorite only")
                }
                ForEach(listData) { data in
                    self.rowView(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func rowView(data: Model) -> some View {
#if DEBUG
        print(">> \(data.value)")
#endif
        return NavigationLink(destination: Text("Details")) {
            Text("Go next from \(data.value)")
        }
    }
}
```

... and right clicking in Preview to select run as Debug Preview we get:

```
2019-10-31 14:28:03.467635+0200 Test[65344:11155167] [Agent] Received connection, creating agent
2019-10-31 14:28:04.472314+0200 Test[65344:11155168] [Agent] Received display message
>> one
>> two
>> three
```

Answer (score 5):

The safest and easiest way to print while debugging in a SwiftUI View.

```
extension View {
    func Print(_ item: Any) -> some View {
        #if DEBUG
        print(item)
        #endif
        return self
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) { number in
                Text("\(number)")
                    .Print(number)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a `printing()` method that includes `print()` and returns `EmptyView` struct.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    func printing(_ items: Any...) -> some View {
        let _ = print(items)
        return EmptyView()
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        
#if DEBUG
        printing(offset)                // prints [(0.0, 0.0)]
#endif

        ZStack {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Debug Preview is no longer supported in the latest versions of Xcode.**

Very easy way to debug your Preview:

> 1. Open your Swift project in Xcode 11.
> 2. Right-click (or Control-click) on the Live Preview button in the bottom right corner of the preview.
> 3. Select Debug Preview.

[How to debug your SwiftUI previews in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8vkqn3ih)

[image]

Comment: I am using XCode 13.4, I cannot get "Live Preview/Debug Preview" out. Am I doing something wrong or something has changed about this for the new XCode version?

Comment: @JoeHuang I update the post. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. It will just work like simple print but inside a view.

```
      func printv( _ data : Any)-> EmptyView{
       print(data)
       return EmptyView()
      }
```

and use it like that

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View  {
    VStack() {
        
        Text("hello To SwiftUI")
        
        printv("its easy to code in SwiftUI")
        
        Text("And Good to have you here")
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following extension on `View` is as intuitive as `print` because it's made to replicate the default `print(_:separator:terminator:)` function signature & behavior.

```
extension View {
    func printUI(_ args: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") -> EmptyView {
        let output = args.map(String.init(describing:)).joined(separator: separator)
        print(output, terminator: terminator)
        return EmptyView()
    }
}
```

---

##### Usage Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            printUI("ContentView", "1")
            printUI("ContentView", "2", separator: ", ", terminator: "\n.\n.\n")
            printUI("ContentView", "3", separator: "; ")

            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

###### Console Output:

> ContentView 1
> ContentView, 2
> .
> .
> ContentView; 3

Answer (score 1):

You can't because you're in a computed property. You need for example a button and in the action you define the print. Or work with breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

// Try this, add a 'return' on a view then the 'print' can stay alive in.

// Option 1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var num: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        print(num)
        
        return  Text("hello")
    
    }
}

// option 2

// **onto a button**

.onTapGesture {
  if true {
 print("Does the Universe have a Purpose?")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
if true {
      print(aVar, "xx")
}

return ZStack {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not print in body structure i.e. a structure which is **some view** type.For print you need to make function out of body structure and call it using button or something else.