# Xcode 12 beta 3 is not printing debug info

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode12

I'm kind of new to Ios development and still figuring out Xcode.

 I have downloaded Xcode 12 beta 3 and I am using SwiftUI. 
I was using Xcode 11 and when I wrote print("something") everything went well.
after upgrading to 12 beta 3 no print statement is working for me and errors are not shown as well.

I am trying to understand if it something I did wrong in Xcode settings or maybe a bug.
Any help or suggestion will do.

btw, the network request doesn't get to the server. I believe it fails before. the server is working properly. Maybe this info can assist someone.

Thanks a lot in advance!

code sample:

```
import Foundation

protocol TodosNetworkServiceProtocol {
    func fetchTodos(includingCompleted: Bool) -> [Todo]
    func update(todo: Todo)
    func add(todo: Todo)
    func toggleIsCompleted(for todo: Todo)
}

// final class means it cant be inharited
final class TodosNetworkService: TodosNetworkServiceProtocol {
    func fetchTodos(includingCompleted: Bool) -> [Todo] {
        guard let todosUrl = URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/todos") else { return [] }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: todosUrl) { (data, response, error)  in
            // Here it gets into the if but print nothing.
            if error != nil { print(error) }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([Todo].self, from: data)
            } catch let err {
                print(err)
                return
            }
            
        }.resume()
        return []
    }
    
    func update(todo: Todo) {
        print("updating todo")
    }
    
    func add(todo: Todo) {
        print("adding todo")
    }
    
    func toggleIsCompleted(for todo: Todo) {
        print("toggeling todo")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print() to Xcode console in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517813/how-to-print-to-xcode-console-in-swiftui)

Comment: I am using Xcode 12 beta 3 and print works fine. Check if by mistake you added some filter in console log which is filtering out all your print message. [console log filter is in bottum right in Xcode]

Comment: @Magnas Its not the same issue. I know how to print. it just doesn't print.
Even the (llb) that some time is there by default, is gone.

thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Prafulla filter is set to All output so I do not believe this is the case..

thanks anyway :)

Comment: I observe same for Live Debug Preview only, submitted feedback to Apple.

Comment: This is still happening for me on Version 12.0.1 (12A7300). I have submitted the bug to apple.

Comment: Xcode 12.3, console logs in 'Debug Preview' prints nothing... Running in Simulator prints log just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

First enable the debug window to open when ever you run a new build. saves you having to go view > debug area > ... or use the keyboard shortcuts.

Then when the debug area opens it hits a breakpoint. Unselect the breakpoint and the debug area will output your print statements